# How to minimize a "partial" convex function over convex set?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

How to solve this problem?

$ \min_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\\
s.t. \mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X},\mathbf{y}\in\mathcal{Y}
$

where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathcal{X}$and $\mathcal{Y}$ are two convex sets, $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ is convex w.r.t. $\mathbf{x}$ but not w.r.t. $\mathbf{y}$.

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no guarantee that you would find the optimal solution for this problem. If f is strongly convex with respect to x then you can find optimal x for each y and the use that x to take the gradient with respect to y ( as the optimizer is unique the function has gradient based on Danskin's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danskin%27s_theorem). In order for the gradient to be smooth as well you need the function in x to be strongly convex and the gradients with respect to x and y to be Lipchitiz on x and y (this is easy to prove and you should be able to find a simple proof for it in the books; but in lemma 1 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10571 that I was coincidentally reading today it proves it for the maximizing strongly concave function). So you can do gradient descent on y with step-size 1 over liptchitz constant and converge to a stationary solution.

Comment: Could you please provide some references for your method? In addition, if  $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ defined in $[0,1]$, then is $f(x)$ strongly convex?

Comment: I added some more references. To answer your other question: the function 1/x is strongly convex in (0,1].

Comment: Thank you very much,  Maziar Sanjabi. By the way, for a convex function, there exist some operations that preserve convexity, such as $f(A\mathbf{x}+b)$ is convex if $f(\mathbf{x}) $ is convex, then my question is that for a strongly convex function, does such operation still hold?

Comment: Not in general. If $A$ is full rank then it holds, but if not it won't be strongly convex anymore.